# When I use Shift + Alt + UpArrow or DownArrow in VScode it goes into Multi-Cursor mode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have vim extension installed in vs code here are it's settings

```
// Vim Extension
    "vim.commandLineModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [],
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [],
    "vim.useCtrlKeys": false,

     // this is optional if you want to remap your vim default esc to jj 
    "vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
      {
        "before": ["j", "j"],
          "after": ["<esc>"]
      }
```

My Key bindings for copying line or down don't work from the shortcuts i.e.

1. Shift + Alt + UpArrow
2. Shift + Alt + DownArrow

[image: Here is the image of Key bindings]

Edit 1: Works if I disable Vim extension.

Comment: use the key binding debugging to see which command is executed on a particular key press

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.

1. Go to Keyboards Shortcuts (Ctrl K + Ctrl S)
2. Search for these key bindings "Shift + alt + UpArrow".
3. Delete the key bindings used by vim by right clicking and selecting remove option.
4. Make sure to remove the vim extension Key bindings not the one used by the editor.